# Why people use JSP?

Tags: ajax, jsp, web

I am new to web develop, so I need to ask some question of JSP.
I am just curious why JSP is used. Since as my understanding, JSON can handle all the works. JSP is a view presentation. But I think only apply ajax in client side definitely can solve the problem.

In web page, most contents should be static view, few part is dynamically changing. So apply an ajax methodology can let client side get a dynamic view easily. But use JSP used in this situation is kind of waster. Correct me if I am wrong.

So when does people use JSP? Any good example website of JSP? what is the advantage?

Comment: AJAX means making a completely separate HTTP request, which has a nontrivial amount of overhead that can have performance implications in some environments. JSPs are processed server-side before the response is sent back to the client with the original request, which means all that dynamic info is sent in one HTTP request (the original one).

Comment: @ajp15243 I  think I got your idea. You mean in one http response send a view. But I thin just send data is enough, client side should know how to layout them. Am I right?

Comment: @adiggo Did you ask yourself why the page is loading so slow, why it can't go through low bandwidth, why CPU, memory, and power usage so high in modern browsers. Why ppl prefer GUI applications over web?

Comment: @RomanC I am kind of agree with you. But in my personal opinion, client side should be responsible to layout cuz we want to reduce work in server. And since currently clent's hardware is way better than before.

Comment: @adiggo It's up to you to decide where you want to work on server-side or on client-side, and it's not concerned JSP/servlet technology. On the client side you would probably use javascript instead of java. And only this slow down a client application up to 10.

Answer (score 0):

JSP isn't just page modification and stuff, its often combined with servlets and other back end technologies.

Think of this for example, let's say you need to display some information from a database? You probably **could** do it in JavaScript, but any client would be able to see your database Information, and manipulate queries and other naughty stuff.

Comment: Using javascript, i am just want to make a request for server, but not able to see the database. I am wondering why not use plain json to send back the data instead of using JSP.